# Sync NSURLRequest With Minimum Data on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, synchronization, nsurlrequest

I need to create a sync `NSURLRequest` but just retrieve the minimum amount of data in order to measure the latency time for that server. Is there any HTTP header I can set to just retrieve the minimum data as possible or anything similar? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make a HEAD request (change `HTTPMethod` to @"HEAD").  That will give you just the HTTP headers for the file you're requesting.  That's about the shortest RTL you can achieve realistically.